# How to lookup and sum multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have 2 dataframes structured as such:

GROUPS:

```
P1      P2      P3      P4
123     213     312     231
345     123     213     567
```

INDIVIDUAL_RESULTS:

```
ID      SCORE
123     23
213     12
312     11
213     19
345     10
567     22
```

I want to add a column to the `GROUPS` which is a sum of each of their individual results:

```
P1      P2      P3      P4      SCORE
123     213     312     231     65
```

I've tried using various `merge` techniques, but have really just created a mess. I feel like there's a simple solution I just don't know about, would really appreciate some guidance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
d1=read.table(text="
P1      P2      P3      P4
123     213     312     231
345     123     213     567",h=T)

d2=read.table(text="
ID      SCORE
123     23
213     12
312     11
231     19
345     10
567     22",h=T)
```

I will be using the `apply` and `match` functions. Apply will apply the match function to each row of d1, match will find the matching values from the row of d1 and d2$ID (their indices) and then take the values in d2$SCORE at those indices. In the end we sum them up.

```
d1$SCORE=apply(d1,1,function(x){
  sum(d2$SCORE[match(x,d2$ID)])
})
```

and the result

```
   P1  P2  P3  P4 SCORE
1 123 213 312 231    65
2 345 123 213 567    67
```

Comment: Perhaps you could explain the logic behind the function you pass to `apply` in plain old English.

Comment: With `apply`, is there a way to specify a range of columns to apply the function to rather than the entire row?

Comment: @FloatingFish You can do it inside the anonymous function `apply(d1,1,function(x){some_function(x[2:5])})`, which will do something only on the columns from 2 to 5.

Answer (score 1):

I would try a slow but could be an intuitive way for new users. I think the difficulty was created by the format of your data `d1`. If you do a little bit of tidy up:

```
library(tidyverse)
d1<-data.frame(t(d1))
colnames(d1) <-c("group1", "group2")
d1$P = row.names(d1)
d1<-d1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = group1:group2, 
    names_to = "Group",
    values_to = "ID"
  )  

df <-left_join(d1, d2, by ="ID")
df

# A tibble: 8 x 4
  P     Group     ID SCORE
  <chr> <chr>  <int> <int>
1 P1    group1   123    23
2 P1    group2   345    10
3 P2    group1   213    12
4 P2    group2   123    23
5 P3    group1   312    11
6 P3    group2   213    12
7 P4    group1   231    19
8 P4    group2   567    22
```

Once you get the data to this more "conventional" format, we can easily work out a `tidyverse` solution.

```
df  %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  summarize(SCORE = sum(SCORE))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Group  SCORE
  <chr>  <int>
1 group1    65
2 group2    67
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to reformat the first data.frame to contain the group and subgroup Information:

```
groups <- tidyr::gather(d1,name,number,P1:P4)
```

These information could be added to the second data.frame and could be further used for different analyses. Such as aggregrations.

```
d2_groups <- merge(groups, d2, by.x = "number",by.y = "ID")

aggregate(d2_groups$SCORE,  by=list(groups = d2_groups$name), FUN=sum)
```