# Nested Match Functions in R

Tags: r, dplyr

This is a follow up to [How to lookup and sum multiple columns in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58451599/how-to-lookup-and-sum-multiple-columns-in-r) :

I have 3 data frames as such:

Groups:

```
P1          P2          P3          P4      
"Joe"       "Sally"     "A.J."      "Mary"  
"Cory"      "Joe"       "Sally"     "Katy"
```

Names:

```
ID      NAME
123     "Joe"
213     "Sally"
312     "A.J."
231     "Mary"
345     "Cory"
567     "Katy"
```

Individual_Results:

```
ID      SCORE
123     23
213     12
312     11
231     19
345     10
567     22
```

My goal is to create a new column in `Groups` with a `SCORE` column that is a sum of each of the results in the group

```
P1          P2          P3          P4          SCORE
"Joe"       "Sally"     "A.J."      "Mary"      65
```

Following the example of the answer in the referenced question above, I've attempted the following

```
groups$score = apply(groups, 1, function(x){
    sum(Individual_Results$SCORE[match(match(x, Names$Name), Individual_Results$ID)])
    })
```

Unfortunately the result is creating the new column, but the result is `NA` for every score.

If I am understanding how to use both the `apply` and `match` correctly, what I am trying to do is `apply` the function to each row, passing `x` (the `Name`) as the parameter to the first `match` function in order to get the `ID` and then matching the returned `ID` to the second `match` to get the score - summing all the scores per row.

I think I am super close, but just not quite there. Appreciate any help!

Comment: With nested match calls, you should really consider reviewing this answer to your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58452922/11355066 Reshaping your data would give you a much easier way to manipulate your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick.

Note that you don't need `data.table`. I just used it to make the example reproducible

```
require(data.table)

Groups <- data.frame(fread('"P1","P2","P3","P4"
"Joe","Sally","A.J.","Mary"
"Cory","Joe","Sally","Katy"'))

Names <- data.frame(fread('ID,NAME
123,"Joe"
213,"Sally"
312,"A.J."
231,"Mary"
345,"Cory"
567,"Katy"'))

Individual_Results <- data.frame(fread('ID,SCORE
123,23
213,12
312,11
231,19
345,10
567,22'))


Groups$SCORE <- apply(Groups, 1, function(x){
  sum(Individual_Results$SCORE[match(Names$ID[match(x, Names$NAME)], Individual_Results$ID)])
})


# Inspect groups:
Groups
#      P1    P2    P3   P4 SCORE
# 1  Joe Sally  A.J. Mary    65
# 2 Cory   Joe Sally Katy    67
```